# How do I create folders and add/update Javascript (use a jQuery framework for my site) on Google sites?

Tags: directory, javascript-framework, google-sites

How do I create folders and add/update Javascript (use a jQuery framework for my site) on Google sites?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make new folders, just add a new page (for example "foo"). Then when you add a second page (called "bar" for example) you can select that it go under "foo"   (so the result is http://sites.google.com/site/yoursitename/foo/bar/

as for javascript, I think you have to build a "gadget" (see http://sites.google.com/site/gsunhelp/step-by-step-guides/buildinggadgetsforgooglesites)

Comment: Is there no easy way to map the tree structure of pages on my Hard disc to Google sites?